# Timing belt issues

Tags: engine, honda, accord, timing-belt, cam-timing

I have a 95 accord (f22b2), While driving it shut down. I have tracked the problem to the bolt holding the camshaft sprocket to the cam backing out, losing keyway or woodruff key. So no camshaft movement no distributor movement car shut down. At the time trying to restart car it sounded like no compression like breaking a timing belt. So after discovering what had happened I just positioned cam sprocket back to keyway hole re-installed a new keyway and everything seemed back to normal visually. Everything back in time, TDC lined up  rotor pointing at #1 so I put everything back together, tried starting, sounds like no compression. Upon further inspection I noticed all exhaust valves were outta lash. I reset them, but adjusters are damn near maxed out. Put everything back together, still sounds like no compression. All the valves are moving that I'm seeing. What's happened? did I ruin something? Why did the exhaust valves do what they did? The intake valves were not affected, or rather didn't need resetting.

Comment: I can not thank you enough for taking the time out to read and answer my question! Gonna take a shot at it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

The F22B2 Honda motor is an *interference motor*. What this means is, the pistons and the valves share the same physical space inside the engine *just not at the same time* ... well, that is if everything is timed correctly. What most likely happened to you is you've bent exhaust valves. When the cam was no longer spinning like it should have been, the valves (in this case it would appear exhaust valves) stayed open and the pistons contacted them causing them to bend out of shape. Since they are now bent, they will no longer seal whatsoever. This is why you don't have any compression. You won't know if it's a single cylinder or all of the cylinders until you do a compression test. At this point, though, I'd suggest a compression test is probably moot, but you may still want to do it to prove what's going on.

To fix this, you'll most likely need to pull the head. Depending on the damage, you may be able to replace valves or in a worst case scenario, you may have to replace the entire head. As an alternative, it may just be cheaper to replace the engine with a used one. These engines should be plentiful and easily found.